# Installing a different version of Windows 7 on laptop

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

I have decided to format the laptop I bought last year. It is a Sony VAIO VPCSB Series.

It shipped with Windows 7 Professional, but now I want to install Windows 7 Home Premium on it. So I did it, formatted the HD and installed the new OS. Once I was done, I noticed the laptop was very, very slow, despite the fact that the OS was clean. The next day, I turned the computer on and this time it was just fine. That made me suspicious and led to the question.

Would it be better to install Windows 7 Pro? Is this a known and common issue when installing a different version of Windows on a laptop?

Comment: Why do you want Home Premium? With Windows 7, the Pro edition is a strict superset of Home Premium - all features in Home Premium are also in Pro.

Comment: The two versions are identical except for a few features that exists and can be enabled on Professional.  The problem you experienced was not connected to the version of `Windows 7` you installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Windows installation process, there are usually about 2 or 3 reboots depending on the software and drivers' configurations. May be you forgot a reboot and when you switched your computer off and on, it completed the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

The Pro Edition has more features, and both versions should run the same.

There are some differences like the memory support (Home Premium supports 16GB of physical memory and the Pro edition supports 192GB of physical memory) and the versions of the processor x86 or x64. But in your case it should make no difference...

The difference is when you install a different OS. If you have XP and install 7, it would run better (if you have the resources)

Try to download the latest drivers from the official page for your OS. You can also check the latest BIOS update